# how to compare three date fields in validation rule

Tags: validation

i was trying to compare three date fields in validation rule and i used this formula

```
 And( (Start_Date__c < Revision_Date__c) , (Revision_Date__c < Close_Date))
```

Close date is a standard field but while creating a record validation rule is not working, even though i m putting wrong dates that will not satisfy my validation rule, record is creating without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to try like this

```
And( (Start_Date__c > Revision_Date__c) , (Revision_Date__c > Close_Date))
```

.. In validation rule always we need to write opposite condition.. So that will be satisfy and validation rule fire

Comment: Always welcome @RAVIGAUTAM

Comment: IF(AND((Service_Start_Date__c >=  Revision_Date__c), (Revision_Date__c >= CloseDate),(Service_Start_Date__c >= CloseDate)),true,false) , dude first time it's working but i am changing the values of date field even though they r satisfying validation rule, error is not coming, nd record is getting save

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM Can you just give me example what you are giving value in field.. PLs add in your question... Also point out when you want error or not

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM look this condition `(Revision_Date__c > Close_Date)` and you entered `rd= 1/15/2016,cd=1/16/2016` it should be `rd= 1/16/2016,cd=1/15/2016` then only it will fire validation.. correct?